# adding audio files iphone app

Tags: iphone, audio, download

can an iphone application download audio files from itunes directly.if yes is there any reference on how to do this any tutorial or link

Answer (score 1):

[image]

by allowing file sharing yes u can add file to your app.

Regards,

Shyam

Comment: i think u misunderstood my question,this is more of programming,i asked if we can download songs from itunes directly to phone using an application.can inapp purchase used to buy songs from itunes